# Mingw build with latest standard support

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, c++17

Is there mingw builds which supports filesystem namespace? 
I'm moving project from vc to mingw, and don't want to add boost filesystem, because currently it works without boost, under gcc/Linux and vc/win with experimental namespace.

Comment: You would rather drag in dependencies to the very latest compiler versions and use experimental features of said compilers than depend on an easy to obtain, free and well-known library? That's unusual design, unless you plan to release in 2020 or so.

Comment: You know, boost version of this library is not a header only and even not a standalone, it brings other boost dependencies, in addition, for some reason project had to be built with auto git clone/build all external libraries. l saw only initial git repository and modularity support in boost, not familiar with this well....

Comment: @Baum as C++17 is feature complete, and FS TS is pretty static, it is probably more future-proofed than boost is at this stage.

Comment: @Yakk: It's not a question of being "future-proof"; it's a question of availability. You don't have to wait for your standard library implementation to catch up.

Comment: @NicolBolas You don't have to wait either *if* mingw already had support.  If it didn't have support, then yes, you'd have to wait: but the question is "does it have support", not "should I use it".

Comment: Seems mingw doesn't have such library. For us, it's not a reason to migrate on boost implementation, but we will stay on vc compiler. Thank you

Comment: @amigo421 Considered c2 instead of mingw?

Comment: What do you mean c2? I only know the backend Microsoft compiler with this name... So I'm currently using this as a part of vc toolchain (c1+c2)

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/737/

Answer (score 1):

MinGW GCC 8.2.0 can work with filesystem without experimental namespace.

Though it works with filesystem only via using `-lstdc++fs` (and of course there should be `-std=c++17` compilation flag or something similar).